# CSRF error on djangorestfull while ajaxing for /api-auth/login

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework, csrf

I'm in server side of web project that use `djangorestfull`. Our UI team runs UI with gulp on port 3000 and `Django` server runs on port 8000. For login we use `/api-auth/login` url for ajax. Answer of option method from `/api-auth/login` contains `csrftoken` and a form but post method (that contains username and password) faces with `CSRF` error. How can I check the source of this problem? Is it in server side or the token won't send with post method?

Here is my `setting.py`:

```
REQUIRED_APPS = [
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

and `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('User.urls', namespace='User')),
    url(r'^schedule/', include('Schedule.urls', namespace='Schedule')),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the UI team. Chances are high they are not including the CSRF token in the POST request. Kindly confirm that. Here are some docs from Django on how to add the token. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax